# How can I link to a specific tab created with Dojo/Zend Combination

Tags: zend-framework, dojo, tabcontainer

I have the following html / Javascript:

http://pastie.org/782618

And the following Zend PHP Code for the tabs:

http://pastie.org/782620

I would like to link to the Second Tab (Event Information2).  If possible I would prefer to be able to have a button on the first tab that when clicked it goes to the next form.  If that isn't possible I could also do a link to the second tab as long as it wouldn't refresh the page (there will be content in a form that will need to not be lost).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out,  for future users:

```
    $next = new Zend_Form_Element_Button ('next', array('onClick'=>"dijit.byId('createEventForm-TabContainer').forward()"));
    $next->setLabel('Next');                   

    $back = new Zend_Form_Element_Button ('back', array('onClick'=>"dijit.byId('createEventForm-TabContainer').back()"));
    $back->setLabel('Back');
```